# Cartesian Product: Unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $\Omega$.

Consider families:
$$A:\Lambda\to\mathcal{P}\Omega\quad B:\Lambda\to\mathcal{P}\Omega$$
and sets $A_0,B_0\in\mathcal{P}\Omega$.

For products one has:
$${\bigcup}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A(\lambda)\times B(\lambda)\supseteq A_0\times B_0\implies\exists\lambda_0\in\Lambda:A(\lambda_0)\times B(\lambda_0)\supseteq A_0\times B_0$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true: Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}$, $\Lambda = \{2,3\}$, $A(2) = \{0\}$, $A(3) = \{1\}$, $B(2)=B(3) = \{0,1\}$.

Then $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A(\lambda) \times B(\lambda) = \{0\} \times \{0,1\} \cup \{1\} \times \{0,1\} = \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$. So $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A(\lambda) \times B(\lambda)$, but $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \not \subseteq A(\lambda) \times B(\lambda)$ for $\lambda = 2,3$.